# Can I show an auto number field (or any other unique ID type value) on a new record before it has been saved?

Tags: opportunity, externalid, auto-number, new

A simple request.  I am customising an opportunities object page layout and want to show a UID type value that staff can quote to people.

I have this working currently with an auto number field but that can't appear when the new record is being created, it only appears once editing the record.

So is there a way around this and also is it possible without workflows ?

Comment: Do you want to show this auto number field on the opportunity standard edit layout when user clicks on the new opportunity button? Just to confirm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an option I can think of.. not a straight forward one thou.. (and there might be an easier option that i can't think of)

1. Create a Custom Setting (hierarchy) with a Number field and start with a base value

[image]

2. Create a New Custom Number Field on Opportunity and set its default value to read from the Custom Setting field.
3. You can mark the field as Read-only in the page layout and it will show up in the New Opportunity page in read only mode.
   [image]
4. Create a Trigger on Opportunity to update this custom setting Number field to next available unique number every time a new Opp is created.

Comment: But OP wants the auto number field to have its value before it hits the database(something like user clicks on the new button and the number should be there) or am I missing something in your solution?

Comment: yup. the trigger in step 2 will create the next available auto number and stores it in the custom setting. so when you click new opportunity you are directly displaying it from the custom setting.

Comment: But the trigger won't fire until user clicks on the save button right? I think OP wants the auto number to show the moment user clicks on the new button(which is what I am guessing from OP question).

Comment: U start with a base number in the custom setting. the 1st opp you create will show u the base number, once the opp is created, the trigger will increment the number in custom setting. so the next opp will show the new value.. does that help ?

Comment: Now I got the picture but I guess read only fields don't show up when user clicks on the New Opportunity button right?

Comment: Hi @VamsiKrishna thanks for your time on this.  A really simple question.. where do I undertake step 1?  I can't find a screen that shows "unique number information" as your screenshot suggests.

Comment: @AdamJones that's just the name of the custom setting i used. if you go to Setup -> Develop -> Custom Settings, you can create your own with any name and add a number field to it. hope it helps.